# What is Amazon's "EAC" library?

Tags: kindle-fire

I've seen lots of references to `<uses-library android:name="eaclibrary"/>` in various Amazon FireOS documentation, but I am not sure what it is.

What is this library? What does it offer? Why use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Amazon](https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/solutions/devices/fire-phone/docs/configuring-your-app-for-fire-phone) [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/solutions/devices/fire-phone/docs/using-the-api-simulator-tool), `eaclibrary` is the Foundation Controls (EAC) library.

> Foundation Controls are building blocks for implementing a basic Fire
>   phone user experience for your app.

It is used to implement Fire phone specific features, e.g. [`HeaderNavigationBar`](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-phone/docs/implementing-headernavigationbar), [`MediaController`](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-phone/docs/implementing-mediacontroller), [`SidePanel`](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-phone/docs/implementing-sidepanellayout), [`TabBar`](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-phone/docs/implementing-tabbar), and [`ToolBar`](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-phone/docs/implementing-toolbar).

See https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-phone/overview/implementing-foundation-controls-for-fire-phone

Comment: Would be really handy to have a purpose-built `MediaController` on FireTV. Hint. Hint.